# Does this second order non-linear PDE have a closed-form solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for real-valued solutions $f(x,y)$ that satisfy:
$$f_{xy}=\alpha\frac{f_xf_y}{f}$$
for $0\le x\le Y$ with boundary conditions $f(0,y)=0$ and $f(Y,Y)=K(Y)$. It might be of interest to not that if I set $g=\log f$, the equation above becomes:
$$g_{xy}=\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}\frac{f_{xy}}{f}$$
I'm not sure if that is useful, but it's as far as I've got in trying to find a solution. Assuming separability $f(x,y)=p(x)q(y)$ seems to lead to trivial solutions. Any clue how to proceed, or if this type of equation has a solution? Do I need to supply more boundary conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, observe that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{f^2}\left(2 \frac{f_x f_y}{f} - f_{x y}\right),
\end{equation}
so if $\alpha = 2$, this takes us a step closer to the solution. The above inspires us (at least, it inspired me) to try
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{1}{f^\beta} = \frac{\beta}{f^{\beta+1}} \left((1+\beta) \frac{f_x f_y}{f} - f_{x y} \right),
\end{equation}
which leads us to conclude that
\begin{equation}
 0 = \alpha \frac{f_x f_y}{f} - f_{x,y} = \frac{f^\alpha}{\alpha-1}\,\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{1}{f^{\alpha-1}}.
\end{equation}
Since the general solution to $g_{xy} = 0$ is given by $g(x,y) = g_1(x) + g_2(y)$, we see that
\begin{equation}
 f(x,y) = \left[f_1(x)+f_2(y)\right]^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}
\end{equation}
solves the PDE, for any suitable choice of $f_{1,2}$.

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting that this solution blows up for $\alpha=1$.

Comment: It certainly is, I didn't notice that at first. Feel free to accept my answer!

Comment: New at this. Accepted!